# How do I efficiently test SQL/JPQL/HQL?

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd

It is often said when unit testing to `dont test the database as that is an integration test` ([see point 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838646/jpa-version-how-to-use-it/1838758#1838758)).

However, SQL/JPQL/HQL encapsulate `data store specific` logic which is often in **string format** on how to access data. This free form string data access command can easily go wrong and hence needs to be tested.

How do i efficiently test this sort of logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a unit test, but there is nothing with using a unit testing framework like Nunit to test your sql. But it IS important that you keep it separated from the real unit tests. Real unit tests are fast and does not communicate with the outside ... nor do they attempt to alter it by updates, deletes and inserts.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get to running a unit test against an SQL (or similar framework) query, is to set up a SQLite database in memory, and run against it.

While that still is technically an integration test, it runs **almost** as fast as a unit test should.

If you do so, just take care to note the *slight* differences between SQLite and your *real* database, and try to make your queries compatible with both.

Hope this helps,
Assaf.